# How can windows start and run without a C compiler?

Tags: c, windows, compilation, operating-system

*I will assume that if you are reading this question and know the answer, then you would almost immediately realize that I am a noob in cs, and I am.*

**Here's the thing:** I know programming languages need a thing called compilers so that the stuff you write can be run by the machine, which only knows on and off, 1 and 0. So, I got curious about that popular language called C from which many other popular languages come. Then, I learn windows and many os (just not to say all of them) are written in C, but at the same time windows doesn't have a built-in C compiler, so to write C code and run it you have to install one.

**That's the whole background story.** After that, I wonder **how it is possible** that my computer runs the actual operating system written in C if there doesn't seem to be any compiler anywhere at all.

So, the question being made, I want to be specific on that I'm not questioning anything at all, as I'm assuming this thing as a fact: windows is written in C, there's no compiler, it runs anyway. I just want to know how that works (or if some of my assumptions are inaccurate or wrong and there lies the answer).

Comment: A compiler is used to translate source code to an executable. You don't need a compiler to run the executable.

Comment: You compile your C code into an executable binary once. Then you can run it multiple times. Windows has already been compiled and doesn't need to be compiled by you.

Comment: Let's take step back - how can a compiler run without a compiler?

Comment: Compilers are not interpreting a script on the fly. C is not a scripting language. Compilation and execution are not done at the same time.

Comment: By the way, everything on a comptuer is "0 and 1". Everything. Even pictures and writing.

Answer (score 2):

A C compiler transforms "text" into something the processor can understand (the `0` and `1` in your question)

For example, the "text"

```
int foo(int bar) {
    return bar * 2;
}
```

could be *hiding* in the middle of this executable

```
00471eb0  14 48 8d 3d 88 03 00 00  48 8d 14 40 49 8b 06 48  |.H.=....H..@I..H|
00471ec0  8d 74 d0 38 31 c0 e8 a5  ec ff ff 49 63 46 14 48  |.t.81......IcF.H|
00471ed0  8d 3d 6a 03 00 00 48 8d  14 40 49 8b 06 48 8d 74  |.=j...H..@I..H.t|
```

Answer (score 1):

A compiler is a program that 'reads' the source, human readable code and converts it to machine code, on the end of this process it generates a binary, a file that the computer can execute, this file is any program from a web navigator to a operating system.

The thing is, once this file is generated, it stays the same and can be run over and over again, without need to recompile.

Note here there is a difference between a compiler and an interpreter, witch reads a script and "translates" it line by line, and needs to be installed to run a program.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I try to explain without too much details.

In your PC you don't have C source code (that's Microsoft propritary :-| ) but there is machine code. Processors can read machine code (exist different type based on architecture) and not source code (the one that you can write).
Compiler translate source into machine code that can be executed by a cpu.